# files in wwwroot\lib get randomly corrupted with msdeploy on TeamCity

Tags: msbuild, teamcity, asp.net-core-1.1

I'm having the strangest behaviour whilst deploying my ASP.Net core app to Azure from Team City.

I'm using msbuild 15.0, and the logs show that at the step where files are copied to the local temp publish folder everything seem to be copied correctly (_CopyResolvedFilesToPublishPreserveNewest). However I always end up with one or two files (not always the same) which get corrupted with duplicate content inserted half way through the files, when at the end I compare the contents of the source wwwroot and the one in PubTmp\Out.

Obviously when it happens on a JS library it makes the whole library (knockout etc.) unusable.

Any clue at what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone stumbles on that, my problem was actually not related to Team City or msbuild, but it was instead a virtualization issue with the build server